# Compare two arraylists with iterators

Tags: java, arraylist, iterator, while-loop

I need to compare two different Arraylists of different sizes.

I can do this with two loops - but I need to use iterators.

The second loop only iterates once instead of n times.

```
while (it.hasNext()) {
    String ID = (String) Order.get(i).ID();
    j = 0;              
    while (o.hasNext()) {   
        String Order = (String) Order.get(j).ID();
        if (myOrder.equals(Order)) {
            //do sth
        }
        j++;
        o.next();
    }
    i++;
    it.next();
}
```

Comment: You seem to misunderstand how iterators are used. If you use an iterator, you don't need to call `String ID = list.get(i).ID();`, you simply call: `String ID = it.next().ID();`.

Comment: Some more details on *I need to compare* would be helpful. Do you want to check if they *contain the same objects* or if they *contain the same objects at the same slots*.

Comment: If you are working with a modern programming IDE (like eclipse), please start using the auto formatting. I will have to make another appointement with my doctor because of eye cancer after reading this code... :P

Comment: Also, you should try to follow the [Java Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367). So, method names should start lowercase (`id()`, not `ID()`) and variable names as well (`String order;`, not `String Order;`). This will optimize readability and will prevent nasty problems with your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use iterators in a much simpler way than you do:

```
Iterator<YourThing> firstIt = firstList.iterator();
while (firstIt.hasNext()) {
  String str1 = (String) firstIt.next().ID();
  // recreate iterator for second list
  Iterator<YourThing> secondIt = secondList.iterator();
  while (secondIt.hasNext()) {
    String str2 = (String) secondIt.next().ID();
    if (str1.equals(str2)) {
      //do sth
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to instantiate the iterator `o` for each iteration of `it`  e.g.

```
while (it.hasNext()) {
   Iterator<String> o = ...
   while (o.hasNext()) {
     // ...
   }
}
```

Nb. you don't need the index variable `j`. You can just call `o.next()` to get the element of the list referenced by the iterator.

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
List<String> areInBoth = new ArrayList(list1);
areInBoth.retainAll(list2);
for (String s : areInBoth)
    doSomething();
```

You'll need to adjust the equals method of your objects to compare the right stuff (IDs in your example).

Comment: He would need to override `equal()` because he is checking for the same `ID()` and not the same instance. If you add this, this answer will be very good. (Although OP mentioned that he **has** to use iterators - for whatever reasons.)

Comment: Thank you for noticing. I misunderstood, I got the sentence like "I can do it using two loops, but I'm disappointed that I don't know any other solution than using the iterators".

Comment: Your solution is very good and I would leave it here, although I guess it doesn't solve the problem of OP.

Answer (score 1):

```
Iterator<Object> it = list1.iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    Object object = it.next();
    Iterator<Object> o = list2.iterator();
    while (o.hasNext()) {   
        Object other = o.next();
        if (object.equals(other)) {
            //do sth
        }
    }
}
```

Two `iterators` because of two lists, get each `object` with check for next and getting the next item (`hasNext()` and `next()`).